# Why are my recent film photo’s coming back grainy/blurry?

Tags: exposure, filters, blur, film-grain

On my last three rolls of film I’ve had developed the pictures have been excessively grainy.
This is apparent on looking, but once zoomed in (even a tiny bit) all definition/detail is lost and the picture is really grainy and undefined.

I was wondering if it was a result of under exposure. I’ve been using a yellow filter so wondered if that was the issue as I wasn’t compensating for it. Although because my camera uses TTL (Minolta x500) and my yellow Hoya K2 filter only has a a filter factor of 2 (1 stop) I thought the film latitude should be able to handle it.

Or perhaps it was the f stop I’d chosen, making it out of focus.

Just a bit confused really.

Previously (without yellow filter) I’ve used tri x 400 (2 rolls) and had no problems.
I’ve also shot three rolls of Lomo 400 and never had an issue with blurry ness/grain/lack of definition when zooming into a pic.

With the yellow filter I’ve had a roll of Delta 400 and HP5 400 that definitely have this problem.

All film was shot at box speed, on the same camera and developed by the same lab.

I’ve attached an image below showing the problem I’m referring to. (Taken on Delta 400 with yellow filter)

I’ve also attached a picture taken in Brighton that doesn’t have this issue. (This was taken tri X 400 without yellow [image]filter)

Apologies if a question like this has been asked and answered already. [image]

Comment: Unless you develop and scan your self, there is no way to know if the process is or is not consistent. The lab may be doing something different like using different staff.

Comment: The second image looks grainier to me than the first. Which is which in your description?

Comment: Seems like you've shot multiple rolls with and without filter since noticing the problem.  Why not try adjusting exposures to compensate for the filter?

Comment: I wonder to what extent this has to do with how we *perceive* grain (rather than what the actual objective granularity of the negative is). To me, the people in the foreground in the second photo look to be considerably out of focus (on zooming), and my guess is that we tend to notice grain more easily in out-of-focus areas (since there's less acutance there connected to the subject matter itself). But this is just a guess.

Comment: Bob - This is very true, once I’ve got more of a handle on shooting etc I plan to try and dev my own. Michael - the second image is the one I’m talking about in terms of grain. Sorry it wasn’t very clear. The whole roll is pretty much like this. I don’t have a prob with grain, I like it. But the second photo doesn’t look ‘correct’. Figured something was wrong with exposure.

Comment: Xiota- the problems with the grain only seemed to happen after the filter. When I look at the date I bought the filter and the dates I shot the rolls. I’ll now compensate and see what happens. 
Kahovius - that’s the problem I’m talking about. Maybe it’s as simple as missing focus leading to the grain. Although it’s in most of the roll. And in the 6 rolls I’d shot prior to the filter I’d never had a problem with focusing. So figured it was more likely something with exposure?

Comment: Thanks all for your comments I appreciate them. I like grain, it’s more the fact of the images not being sharp, especially when zoomed in. When I’ve never had this problem before. 

I’ll try a roll compensating for the filter and also a roll without the filter as that will rule it in or out. 
It’s only a yellow filter so I thought my TTL metering and the latitude of the film would compensate. 
I’ll just keep shooting and see what happens. 

Thanks again for the comments.

Comment: TTL metering should handle the filter on its own; that's its job. It manages the exposure to match the light that's coming Through The Lens. If there's a filter there's less light, and the camera will increase the exposure accordingly. Film latitude shouldn't be involved.

Answer (score 2):

Kodak TriX is known for distinctive and traditional grain structure. Ilford Delta films are T grained. Lomography films are known for...well the fun is in the surprise.

Consistent results with film come from consistent film selection, metering, scene conditions, filter selection, developer, processing times, and scanning.

You have inconsistent results because there is no consistency except the choice of lab. And there are zero guarantees that the lab work is consistent. Many labs are not.

These are the joys of film.